# Find the property from JCR using CQ Extjs without knowing the exact path

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem, jcr

I need to find property value using ExtJs. I dont know the exact path of the node. For example When we trigger a workflow in AEM, AEM automatically creates node under "/etc/workflow/instances" based on date. Assume that I need to find a property called 'checkUser' under /etc/workflow/instances/2015-02-12/model_*****/data/metaData node, How Do i find 'checkUser' property using ExtJs.

I knew that we can accomplish this by using java API, hasNode, getNode, hasProperty("checkUser') methods.
I need to do the same thing in CQ EXtJs. Has anyone tried to accomplish using extjs.

Is there any methods in CQ ExtJs to find a property? I found that 'CQ.WCM.getPageInfo' method which gives us the page information. But it does not have method to find a jcr property.
 Please guide me.

Comment: What about making an XHR request to the node and grabbing its properties via json?  For example: /etc/workflow/instances/2015-02-12/model_*****/data/metaData.json.  This will give you all the properties you need.  You can use CQ.Ext.Ajax to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes I agree with  @Woodfier that seems the best way to achieve this.